# scraping data using xpath php and domdocument gettin inner content of certain table

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

There is a external page from where I need the data. Its some type of a list you can get with restaurant orders. now this page has tables... each table has a class telling wich kind of table it is for example " deliverd orders"

Inside these tabes there are rows and tds.. i need the td values of each row for my data array...

so what i do.. i do a xpath query gettin the contents of the table with class status kitchen. This works... but now i need all the rows and tds inside this table... seperated by class for example `<td class="orderode">0000</td>` i need as `'ordercode' => val` in my array.. so i did another loop inside the loop with another xpath query

but now i see all order codes not only of kitchen... because it parses the whole html again... i just want to do the query on the parent foreach result or something.. How can I do this?

```
$result = array();
$html = $sc->login(); //curl result
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$classname = "order-link wide status-kitchen";
$td = $xPath->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");

foreach($td as $val){

    $classname = "code order-code";
    $td2 = $xPath->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");
    foreach($td2 as $v){

        $result[] = $v->nodeValue;
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

example of how the HTML looks:

/* Order list of kitchen */

```
<table class="order-list">
      <tbody class="order-link wide status-kitchen" rel="#oQOP3PRN511"> // REPEAT
        <tr>
          <td class="time">17:43</td>
          <td class="time-delivery ">
            18:45           </td>
          <td class="code order-code">00000</td>
          <td>address data</td>
          <td class="distance">
                        </td>
          <td class="amount">€ 29,75</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tbody class="order-link wide status-kitchen" rel="#oQOP3PRN511"> //REPEAT
        <tr>
          <td class="time">17:43</td>
          <td class="time-delivery ">
            18:45           </td>
          <td class="code order-code">00000</td>
          <td>address data</td>
          <td class="distance">
                        </td>
          <td class="amount">€ 29,75</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>

/*order list deliverd */
<table class="order-list">
      <tbody class="order-link wide status-kitchen" rel="#oQOP3PRN511"> //REPEAT
        <tr>
          <td class="time">17:43</td>
          <td class="time-delivery ">
            18:45           </td>
          <td class="code order-code">00000</td>
          <td>address data</td>
          <td class="distance">
                        </td>
          <td class="amount">€ 29,75</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tbody class="order-link wide status-kitchen" rel="#oQOP3PRN511"> //REPEAT
        <tr>
          <td class="time">17:43</td>
          <td class="time-delivery ">
            18:45           </td>
          <td class="code order-code">00000</td>
          <td>address data</td>
          <td class="distance">
                        </td>
          <td class="amount">€ 29,75</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run your second xpath query starting with a given node in the DOM, begin the query with `.` and pass the context node as a second parameter to `query()`.

#### Example:

```
$td2 = $xPath->query(".//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]", $val);
```

Answer (score -3):

You want to avoid using HTML DOM and similar things for HTML scraping, as they will not prase certain type of invalid HTML, and particularly have problems with tables.

To get all trs:

```
preg_match_all( '~<tr.*?>(.*?)<\/tr>~is', $page, $trs );
foreach( $trs as $tr )
{
    preg_match_all( '~<td.*?>(.*?)<\/td>~is', $tr, $tds );
    print_r( $tds );
}
```

This gets all TR elements, with any or no attributes and any or no inner HTML. The i flag means case insensitive and the s flag means that it will include \n in . matches. Then the same for TD.

See a class I posted here that does the same thing:

[Get Inner HTML - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20725068/get-inner-html-php)

Though I have not used this for years, I am not sure on the func. I just use reg ex stand alone.

**UPDATE**: Using the above class:

```
$c = new HTMLQuery( $html );
$tbs = $c->getElements( 'tbody', 'class', 'order-link wide status-kitchen' );
print_r( $tbs );
// you could then call a new HTMLQuery and query trs, etc., or:
foreach( $tbs as $tb )
{
    preg_match_all( '~<tr.*?>(.*?)<\/tr>~is', $tb, $trs );
    foreach( $trs as $tr )
    {
        preg_match_all( '~<td.*?>(.*?)<\/td>~is', $tr, $tds );
        print_r( $tds );
    }
}
```

Comment: i need to get the trs of the tbody with a class called <tbody class="order-link wide status-kitchen" then i need the content of the TRs... how can i do this with your solution?

Comment: If you look at the link to the class I posed above, you can 'query' the HTML by attributes. I'll post above...

Comment: I use regular expression on a near-daily basis for HTML extraction. If it fails, it's because of bad regEx.

Comment: This will cause all kinds of problems. You should really give DOM another try.

Comment: What kind of problems? I have been using regEx to scrape for seven years. I have not had any issues with using it on HTML, text or PDFs. PHP DOM is unsuitable to scrape with, as it is unable to handle a whole host of badly formed HTML. Even if the HTML you want is well-formed, some bad-form elsewhere can make what you want irretrievable. You can use methods to clean the HTML, but then the HTML may change into various forms that differ from the original. I have also been using XML DOM, XSL and XPath for 7 years; so know of their uses and scraping is not one.

Comment: I just scraped 138,278,058 TR rows from tables this week using the above reEx for TR & TD. The advertised number of rows in the data was 138,278,058. Did not face the 'all kind of problems' you are talking about.

Comment: It's hard to believe you've been at it that long because parsing html with regex is a rookie mistake (hence the downvotes). Have you looked into libraries like simple_html_dom or phpQuery?

Comment: You're not actually providing any substance to your argument. You are just saying 'this is bad', then not backing that up with any reasoning. Nor has anyone else. I understand that regEx has limitations for parsing HTML, but so does DOM and simple XML, one of which I have outlined. Just as RegEx presents issues for scrapping. So does DOM, bar what I have already outlined, if you are scraping based on an elaborate XPath, and there is some variation, you will not get a result, which I believe is essentially the same reason you are using to trash regEx for scrapping.

Comment: If you do actually want to outline why RegEx is bad for scrapping, I will agree with you, and tell you what you do to take those issues into account.

The reason I do not use DOM is because, when I first started I used it as it seemed to best option. However I came across several sites where DOM would not extract the HTML, among others it could not extract tables from botched Joomla-style HTML. Nothing would get around this, not even Tidy could help. And it would not be a good idea to use a HTML modifier which could change your target in all kinds of ways.

Comment: If you get 'all kinds of problems' it because you do not know regEx, and how it can be used to extract what you want from any kind of document, without any issues, bar an issue that you will get with DOM: the HTML varies from page to page in a way that will require multiple extraction methods.

Having said that, I will look at the phpQuery you mention. If it does not have the same pitfalls as DOM it could be useful.